# SharpSquare Async for SearchVenue in FourSquare api

Tags: c#

I am using SharpSquare Async SDK for using Foursquare in .net, which is in the address:

https://github.com/alfeg/SharpSquare

I want simply call searchVenues and get the result but in browser it is waiting and waiting and waiting... I appreciate any help.

here is my code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

parameters.Add("ll", "40.7, -74");
parameters.Add("limit", "10");
parameters.Add("intent", "browse");

Task<List<Venue>> myTask = sharpSquare.SearchVenues(parameters);

myTask.Wait();

List<Venue> myvenue = myTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

foreach (Venue v in myvenue)
{
    Response.Write("venue: " + v.name);
    Response.Write("contact: " + v.contact);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps not directly related to your problem, but you should ideally use `await myTask` or at least `myTask.Result` instead of `myTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: I have tried with myTask.Result, but still no hope